# Objective C Selector not defined in interface but still OK

Tags: objective-c, methods, selector

First post. Trying to learn objective C. I have decent OOP knowledge. I have a bit of C, C++ and Java background but rusty. Unfortunately I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around some Objective C concepts and syntax.

I'm trying out some code in compileonline and after some comment outs i got my code to work but noticed that my method declaration was still commented out. See **initWithName**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface cl_person: NSObject
{
    NSString* name;
    int age;
}

//-(id)init;
//-(id)initWithName: (NSString*)p_name withAge: (int)p_age;
-(void)display;

@end

@implementation cl_person
/*
-(id)init{

  return self;
}*/

-(id)initWithName: (NSString*)p_name{

  //self = [self init];
  name = p_name;
  return self;
}


-(id)initWithName: (NSString*)p_name withAge: (int)p_age{

  self = [self initWithName: p_name];
  age = p_age;
  return self;  
}

-(void)display{

  printf("My name is %s and I am %d years old.", [name UTF8String], age);
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  cl_person *o_person = [[cl_person alloc] initWithName: @"Dick" withAge: 25];   
  [o_person display];
  [o_person release];

  //NSLog (@"hello world");
  [pool drain];
  return 0;
}
```

1. I assume (id)initWithName is a method of NSObject so implementing it directly means overriding the method of the super class. Am I correct?
2. According to the apple dev docs, selectors are part of the Method signature - not to mention the input types and their order but a few things in this example confuses me. Why was I allowed to implement a method with selector withAge even though this was not declared?

Apologies if this was already covered elsewhere. I did a quick search and browsed through some possibly related hits but none helped. Thanks!

[NSTotalNoob release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, that method is specific for this class.
2. I'm not sure what you mean by "implement a method with selector withAge". The name of that method is initWithName:withAge:. All of that is part of one name. There is no requirement in Objective-C to declare your methods. You should declare them in the .h file if you want them to be seen from outside the class. I've seen some people say that you can still call them from outside the class, but you will get compiler warnings -- however, underARC with the default settings you get in Xcode, you can't do this, you'll get an error, not just a warning from the compiler.

Since you're a total noob, by your own account, I should mention a few other things. Normally, in OS X and iOS we don't put any code other than what the template provides in the main.m file. Class names should start with a capital letter, and methods, ivars, and properties should start with a lowercase letter. We also use camel case for naming rather than underscores, so your class would better be written as ClPerson, and the instance as oPerson.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just a follow up..

"There is no requirement in Objective-C to declare your methods. You should declare them in the .h file if you want them to be seen from outside the class."

2.1 Does this mean any method I create in the implemtation that are not declared in the interface is essentially a private method?

2.2 Also, Wouldn't calling the method in main() be classified as outside the class? How come it worked?


Also, thanks for the quick tutorial on the conventions.

Comment: @NSTotalNoob 2.1 Yes, in a sense -- there are no truly private methods in Objective-C, but not declaring them, does hide them. I think you can always call a method with performSelector: whether it's declared or not. 2.2 I don't know the answer to that one. Maybe you're not using ARC? Did you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: nope i dont think so. Just read about arc - no more retain/release :). I think I have an old copy of the sdk (2010). I'll try it out as soon I can get a copy of the new sdk. I was using an online compiler though compileonline.com .. maybe thats the problem :) thanks for the help sir! really appreciate it.